# How do popular websites allow you to log-in from other websites like Facebook?

Tags: authentication, information-retrieval

And how do they get information from these sites? Is there some common way of exposing this information with the users consent? How can they tell if you've authenticated with the external webpage? Is it several different APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use a special Javascript API that Facebook has created, which I believe runs on a protocol called OAUTH.  The complete details can be found at the Facebook developer page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3

Once a person is logged in, you can get their information like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Then facebook sends back their information as a JSON object called data

Answer (score 2):

Social Networks makes use of [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). 
Quoting from wikipedia:

> OAuth is an open standard for authorization. OAuth provides client
>   applications a 'secure delegated access' to server resources on behalf
>   of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to
>   authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing
>   their credentials.

You can have a look at these:

Facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth

Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

You can get list of libraries for different languages here: http://oauth.net/2/